# How to run on Windows with only local CRT DLLs?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, msvcrt, vcredist

I have an application that is intended to be deployed with all MSVC dependencies side-by-side in order not to require administrator access to install the MSVC redistributables. The only system-wide DLLs it should depend on are .NET. I haven't figured out a way to test this capability without installing it on a totally stock machine and testing it there, which is rather inconvenient for both manual and automated (CI) testing.

Is there a reasonably simple way in Windows to turn off or intercept SxS lookup for certain DLLs?

Comment: [Activation Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/activation-contexts) may be able to address part of what you're looking for. But the CRT is loaded even before any of your code runs, so you cannot control that from your code. An application manifest would be the only place I can think of that might give you control over that part.

Comment: It seems incredible that Microsoft would develop a way for applications to load the CRT without it being installed system-wide, but not have a way to test it on systems with Visual Studio installed (which installs the system-wide CRT).

Comment: Applications don't load there CRT. The OS loader does while resolving imports. If you need to test whether your application runs on a clean Windows installation, run it on a clean Windows installation. If spinning up a VM with a fresh image appears to be inconvenient (which *is* the solution to your problem) then maybe you need to invest into more recent hardware. If that is not an option and you wish to monitor where binaries are loaded from enable Loader Snaps. It seems rather incredible to assume that Microsoft were responsible for doing *your* job.

Comment: @MattChambers That's supposed to work out of the box if you put all dependencies in the application directory. See the "*local deployment*" sections for the [VC runtimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deployment-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019) and [UCRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment?view=vs-2019) (with the Win10 caveat).

Comment: Anther option for testing is [Windows Sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview). Whenever you launch Windows Sandbox you get a clean system based on your local system's service level. It's like a VM without the hassle of needing to install a VM or provisioning an image. It starts up in seconds and won't leave any traces behind after being terminated. It provides all the convenience you seem to be looking for.

Comment: OK, applications don't load the CRT. It seems incredible that Microsoft would develop a way for the OS to load the CRT for an application without it being installed system-wide, but not have a way to test it on systems with Visual Studio installed (which installs the system-wide CRT). Our TeamCity builds our app on an EC2 instance with Visual Studio installed. It would be convenient (and more cost effective!) to also test on that instance rather than spinning up another instance.

Comment: Does Windows Sandbox run on AWS? My googling is inconclusive. My previous attempts to run UI applications in Windows containers (which Sandbox seems to be based on) were unsuccessful. I was thinking of using Windows containers to parallelize our GUI functional tests so we could run 3 or 4 at a time instead of 1 at a time.